# I'm building a php web scraper and preg_match gives an error

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, undefined

I'm building an ebay web scraper and the preg_match for price throws an error.

```
preg_match('/<title>([^<]+)<\/title>/i', $data, $matches);
$title = $matches[1];

preg_match('/<img id="icImg"[^>]*src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*>/i', $data, $matches);
$img = $matches[1];

preg_match('/<span id\=\"prcIsum\"\>([^<]+)<\/span>/i', $data, $matches);
$price = $matches[1];
```

The title and the img are being scraped okay but I get this PHP error on price span element: PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is fairly self explanatory; `$matches[1]` doesn't exist. This is probably because there is no match in the `$data` string.

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it
>   does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

```
$isMatch = preg_match('/<title>([^<]+)<\/title>/i', $data, $matches);
if($isMatch == 1){
    $title = $matches[1];
}


$isMatch = preg_match('/<img id="icImg"[^>]*src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*>/i', $data, $matches);
if($isMatch == 1){
    $img = $matches[1];
}

$isMatch = preg_match('/<span id\=\"prcIsum\"\>([^<]+)<\/span>/i', $data, $matches);
if($isMatch == 1){
    $price = $matches[1];
}
```

Perhaps you should make sure the regex is valid for the `$data` you are using and that it does in fact return matches.

Comment: The $data simply holds the ebay url 

    `$data = file_get_contents('http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Original-Apple-iPhone-5S-Gold-64GB-iOS-7-8MP-Unlocked-Smart-Phone-By-FedEx-/221320754748?&_trksid=p2056016.m2518.l4276');`

Answer (score 1):

It is not preg_match() that throws error but when you assign $matches[1](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) it fails because there are no matches returned by function. So you need to check your REGEX. Also there's no sense in using preg_match for HTML parsing. You can use [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php). For this regex to work u need add "m" modifier. But the better solution would be:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($data); //where $data is HTML

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='prcIsum']");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo $element->nodeName;
    echo $element->nodeValue;
  }
}
```

The other option is to use [getElementById()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) method.

This is changed example from php.net site.

Comment: I'm trying to get the price span value from Ebay, and it has the id of prcIsum, checking the Source Code I can see it, is there something that blocks php finding it?

Comment: @Radu033: Most probably some `JavaScript` that actually outputs the content.